# Using the public IP on AWS from java getCanonicalHostName method

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-zeppelin

I'm trying to use AWS as a scalable analytics tool. I'm using apache zeppelin as an interactive shell to a Spark cluster and trying to plot using wisp. This is causing a problem as the plotting approach in wisp is to start a web app based on what I think is a jetty server. This works well on my local machine but on AWS it does not work as it picks up the private IP address rather than the public one.

Within wisp, it uses `java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost.getCanonicalHostName`
to retrieve the IP address of the machine. This always returns the private FQDN address. How can I make the java function return the public IP address or FQDN AWS provides without hardcoding something in wisp every time I spin up a cluster and rebuilding?

I have tried changing /etc/hosts and /etc/hostname but both have no effect. I don't really know where `java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost.getCanonicalHostName`
is getting it's address from.

Any help or advice greatly appreciated.

Dean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot. It was a port issue. It appears that despite displaying the private IP, it's still available on the public IP.

Turn off the internal firewall with `sudo ufw disable` (on an ubuntu vm anyway, look up the alternative command for your flavour of vm).

Next, go to the AWS EC2 Management page for your account and click on the security group of your instance.

On the security group page, edit the inbound rules and add a custom tcp rule.

Under ports,  put in '1 - 65536' and under source put in '0.0.0.0/0'. Please note, that what you have just done is open all ports on your instance to all incoming traffic from everywhere. You have just put down a welcome mat to the internet. I do not recommend doing this long term and it is extremely stupid. It worked for my proof of principle set up though and that is all I was aiming to do. I'll now be looking at ways to make it secure.

Thanks to everyone for their restraint in not mocking me for being a moron.